# Custom fonts in Xcode playground

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I am writing the interface layout in code. As it is annoying to reload application every time I am testing font size or view layout pixel by pixel, i started doing it in playground. That does help a lot. But I do miss my custom fonts there.

Is there a way to add custom fonts to your playground ?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: @Jan Hope you saw the answer below...

Answer (score 27):

First, add the .ttf file to the resources of your playground.  Then you can load the font like this:

```
let cfURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Proxima Nova Semibold", withExtension: "ttf") as! CFURL

CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(cfURL, CTFontManagerScope.Process, nil)

let font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size:  14.0)
```

The filename of the .ttf file does not usually match up with the actual desciptor name of the font, which you need for the UIFont name.  To find that, open up the .ttf file in Font Book on your mac, look at its details, and look for the PostScript name.  That's the name to look for in UIFont(name:...)

Alternatively you can look for your installed font after registering the URL with the following code:

```
var fontNames: [[AnyObject]] = []
for name in UIFont.familyNames() {
    println(name)
    if let nameString = name as? String
    {
        fontNames.append(UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(nameString))
    }
}
fontNames
```

Comment: For swift3, use:

let fontURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ProximaNova-Semibold", withExtension: "ttf")
CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(fontURL! as CFURL, CTFontManagerScope.process, nil)

Comment: To add font to playground resources CMD + 1 to open Navigator panel, and then Resources directory is right there. Press + button at bottom of navigator panel.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to **Chris Garrett** answer, please find the code for **Swift 4** :

```
let cfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SanaSansAlt-Black", withExtension: "otf")! as CFURL
CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(cfURL, CTFontManagerScope.process, nil)
var fontNames: [[AnyObject]] = []
for name in UIFont.familyNames {
   print(name)
   fontNames.append(UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: name) as [AnyObject])
}
```